# Two's complement in C++ - invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, twos-complement

I'm trying to implement some sort of a two's complement algorithm in C++ and so far I think my logic is correct. However, I get the following error when I run it `invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a[4] = {0, 2, 3, 5};
    int b[4] = {9, 7, 8 ,4};

    int sum = 0;
    int transmit = 0;
    int c{0};

    for (int k=3;k>0;k--){
        sum = a[k]+b[k]+transmit;
        c[k+1]=sum%10;
        transmit=sum/10;
    }

    c[0] = transmit;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: @hagubear it is correct, it counts as brace initialisation and for `int` is equivalent to `int c(0);`.

Comment: @sjdowling       yes switched my brain from Java just now. Thanks.

Comment: How is your code related to the two's complement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your purpose is to do plus operation of two int arrays?
A little explanation: you have to declare five units for 'c' as there may be one additional carrier (you called transmit)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a[4] = {0, 2, 3, 5};
    int b[4] = {9, 7, 8 ,4};

    int sum = 0;
    int transmit = 0;
    int c[5] = {0};

    for (int k=3;k>0;k--){
        sum = a[k]+b[k]+transmit;
        c[k+1]=sum%10;
        transmit=sum/10;
    }

    c[0] = transmit;
    return 0;
}
```

With this format: array of decimal integers, they are somewhat hard to be converted to a binary directly. But I can still try to give out a solution:

```
// first convert to an unsigned int
unsigned int result = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
    result *= 10;
    result += c[k];
}

// then convert to binary
char binary[32]; // 32bit should be enough
int len = 0;
while (result > 0) {
    binary[len++] = (result % 2) + '0';
    result /= 2;
}

// finally print binary
for (int k = len - 1; k >= 0; --k) {
    printf("%c", binary[k]);
}
```

The full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a[4] = {0, 2, 3, 5};
    int b[4] = {9, 7, 8 ,4};

    int sum = 0;
    int transmit = 0;
    int c[5] = {0};

    for (int k=3;k>0;k--){
        sum = a[k]+b[k]+transmit;
        c[k+1]=sum%10;
        transmit=sum/10;
    }

    c[0] = transmit;

    // first convert to an unsigned int
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; ++k) {
        result *= 10;
        result += c[k];
    }

    // then convert to binary
    char binary[32]; // 32bit should be enough
    int len = 0;
    while (result > 0) {
        binary[len++] = (result % 2) + '0';
        result /= 2;
    }

    // finally print binary
    for (int k = len - 1; k >= 0; --k) {
        printf("%c", binary[k]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Empty output. It should return a two's complement result.

Comment: @dwvaxaz: The output is empty because you never did anything with `c[]` after calculating it.

Comment: @dwvaxaz The main algorithm you wrote in your code indicates that you want to do a plus operation of two int arrays. The reason of empty output is just because there is no printf called to output. But at last, they are not anything about two's complement. A two's complement is a common representation of signed integers. Please reference the concept here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: `0x28fed0` which is correct but how can I represent in in binary only?

Comment: @dwvaxaz Two's complement is about representing a signed integer in binary foramt. If you need that, I can give you another code piece.

Comment: Yes, please if you'd be so kind :)

Comment: Or in other words how can I print the array appropriately. I don't just `cout << c;`

Comment: Empty output this time.

Comment: Add a printf("\n");  before return if you are in LINUX.

Answer (score 4):

`c` is of type `int`

```
int c{0};
```

And you are trying to deference it as if it was an array:

```
c[k+1]=sum%10;
```

You cannot legally dereference an `int`.

Comment: In which case, how am I supposed to go around this?

Comment: @dwvaxaz make `c` an array or a `std::vector` that is appropriately sized.